# parsley.js v2.3.7 is window.Parsley.addValidator still the correct syntax for a custom validator?

Tags: parsley.js

I am using parsley.js v2.3.7.

Is **window.Parsley.addValidator()** still the correct syntax for adding a custom validator?

Is the Parsleyjs.org documentation kept current?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.Parsley
      .addValidator('multipleOf', {
        requirementType: 'integer',
        validateNumber: function(value, requirement) {
          return 0 === value % requirement;
        },
        messages: {
          en: 'This value should be a multiple of %s',
          fr: 'Cette valeur doit être un multiple de %s'
        }
      });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good.

Yes, as you can see if some live examples.

Yes, as you can see from the commit lists.

Why?